# mod_evasive for nginx?

Tags: apache, nginx, mod-evasive

I am using mod_evasive for apache which manages DOS, that is it automatically blacklist IP's that do too much http queries during a delta time.

Does it exists on nginx ?

Answer (score 10):

No, it doesn't. But you can use ngx_http_limit_req_module.
For more information about this module, look for documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

Answer (score 1):

According to Nginx [Module comparison matrix](http://wiki.nginx.org/ModuleComparisonMatrix) the HttpLimitZoneModule is equivalent to mod_evasive of apache.

This directive is made obsolete in version 1.1.8, an equivalent limit_conn_zone directive with a changed syntax should be used instead.

Further instructions for new module and directives can be found [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html).

Comment: Dead link, archived version [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150906082747/http://wiki.nginx.org/ModuleComparisonMatrix). It says LimitZone is comparable to mod_evasive in **lighttpd**, not Apache.